# access - showing multiple queries in one form

Tags: ms-access

I am new to access, and I am trying to make a simplae project of managing users.

I have a table of USERS, and to more tables of SERVICES and GAMES.
I have connections of ID in USERS, and ID -> USER_ID in SERVICES, as well in GAMES.

Now I want to display in one form, USER profile, and to print the games related to the user and the services related to the user.

I added a query, that joins with USERS and SERVICES and GAMES, and it shows everything right, except that if the user for example has two services and only one game connected to the USER_ID, then it prints the game twice.

is there a way to display it correctly?
in normal SQL and PHP, it would be easy, though in access I have no idea how to do it.

thaks

Comment: Post your queries and schema. We need to see what you're trying.

Comment: 1. How would you do it in SQL? 2. If I had to do this in Access, I would create a tabbed form USER and two sub forms - one for Games and one for Services.

Comment: If I would do it in PHP and SQL, I would just do two different queries and print them in the same page, but in different places on the page.
on would be something like: SELECT * FROM 'SERVICES' WHERE SERVICES.UID = USERS.ID
and then process the result on the page, and in the same page run another query for the GAMES table.

in access any ideas?